# Getting the real client ip on NodeJs behind a NodeBalancer on Linode

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, linode

I have a Linode Kubernetes cluster and my Linodes are running NodeJs. On my Linodes I need to get the IP of the client that requested the application. These x-forwarded-for, x-real-ip, remote-address headers do not work, I even tried with upper and lower case. They always return the IP of the NodeBalancer.

These tutorials are what I found about this topic, but nothing works with NodeJs.
https://www.linode.com/community/questions/23073/get-the-client-ip-behind-a-loadbalancer
https://www.linode.com/community/questions/17963/how-do-i-see-the-real-ip-address-of-a-connection-through-a-nodebalancer
https://www.linode.com/docs/products/networking/nodebalancers/guides/client-ip/

Would be great if someone already faced this challenge and could provide a proper solution. Thanks in advance :)